# Minecraft custom skin not working in game and only shows default skin Alex

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play on Minecraft Java edition, I wanted a custom skin so I went to skin dex for a skin I like and uploaded it to my account and made sure it was equipped in the launcher.
However, when I went into the game, I clicked single player, created a new world but I was just Alex. I also tried to play multiplayer, but no local servers appeared. I’ve been looking everywhere for a fix, but I haven’t found one. The problem is still happening.

When I bought the game it gave me the option to pick a Java account or Microsoft account. I picked Microsoft because I already had one, so is that why it won’t work? I really don’t know, I’m always connected to internet so I can’t be offline.

Somebody please help.

Comment: Does your Microsoft account have Minecraft purchased?

Comment: Yes i purchased Minecraft and when it told me to log in I picked the Microsoft account option

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways I can think of,

1. Check the Skins Server

Minecraft has an entire server dedicated to players’ skins in the game. This server is responsible for allowing players to create skins for the game, implement them in the game, and ultimately display them in the game when you play online. Sometimes, your skin might not be showing in the game because this server could be currently down. It is recommended that you check whether or not this is the case before exploring further solutions for the issue. In order to do this, all you’ll have to do is view the server status from the official Minecraft help page. You’re going to have to wait a while for custom skins to start working again if the server is indeed down.

2. Change Game Version

Unless you’re currently playing Minecraft version 1.7.9 or higher, it is recommended that you switch your game version. Version 1.7.8 and earlier take about an hour or two to load your skins which is why you won’t be able to see them immediately. Unless you’re ok with waiting that long, it is recommended that you decide to switch to one of the newer versions. You’ll also have to definitely change the version if you’re using version 1.3 or earlier and want to use custom skins, as these aren’t compatible with the feature.

3. Correct the Dimensions

It is possible that the dimensions for your skin are wrong if it is a custom skin that you created. Anything bigger than 64×64 will cause issues with the game and the skin won’t show at all. Because of this, the game will automatically revert you back to the default skin instead. It is recommended that you check the dimensions and make sure that they’re correct and not larger than 64×64. If this was indeed the issue, all you have to do is fix the dimensions and then try playing the game again. Your custom skin should now show up in the game.

Comment: Nope I’ve download correct skin dimensions I don’t think the servers are down and I am currently playing on 1.17.1 even when I try to put on the Steve skin which is already there when I get into a single player game it just shows up as Alex and I can’t even play multiplayer because no local servers appear and server ips or whatever never work